# Parsing JSON with C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Currently I have a JSON body that I would like to deserialize into a list of objects in C#. The JSON looks very similar to this:

```
{
    "123": {
        "id": "123",
        "description": "Element 1",
        ...
    },
    "456": {
        "id": "456",
        "description": "Element 2",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

My current structure is as follows:

```
class FooList
{
    public Dictionary<int, Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

and utilising NewtonSoft I am attempting the following:

```
// json = string representation of json data
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooList>(json);
```

This doesn't work. I have managed to deserialize single instances of Foo with the previous line of code, but I am unsure how I can handle the process when the JSON doesn't have a set root element and comprises a list of objects with dynamic root elements.

Apologies if this question has been answered previously, either I am using incorrect language to describe the issue or the answer doesn't seem to exist.

Edit: "This doesn't work" equates to returning an instance of FooList with Foos as null.

Comment: _This doesn't work_  - your screen blacks out, your mouse starts levitating, the data comes out backward?

Comment: Valid point, that was very vague. I have made an edit. Thank you!

Comment: Remove `FooList` from your program entirely. Then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Foo>>(json);`

Comment: Thank you, that has definitely solved the problem.